# Вопрос по поводу кавычек в прямой речи «...акции „Райских кущ!“»

Tags: пунктуация

Есть переводная фраза:

**«Завтрак с Фредди! Гипнопедия — учитесь во сне! Курс читает Фредди! Покупайте акции „Райских кущ!“».**

Меня смущает восклицательный знак в названии фирмы "Райские кущи". По идее, этот знак должен относиться ко всей фразе *"Покупайте акции „Райских кущ“!"*, и точки после кавычек быть не должно. Можно ли именно так ставить восклицательный знак в предложении с двойными кавычками?

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Да, именно так. Без контекста было непонятно, но ваш фразмент расставил все точки над i.

Answer (score 1):

Первое. Если название фирмы - без восклицательного, то его в кавычках (внутренних) быть не должно. Ни при каких обстоятельствах.

Второе. Если знак относится к "покупайте!"  - которые у Вас лапочки в заголовке, то он и дожен быть вне внутренних кавычек.

Третье. При таком построении: (*«Завтрак с Фредди! Гипнопедия — учитесь во сне! Курс читает Фредди! Покупайте акции „Райских кущ“!».*), если кавычки внешние присутствуют в тексте оригинала (прямая речь, например), то последняя точка при **этом не опускается.** Это спорный момент русской пунктуации, но в Вашем случае, думаю, особых сомнений не должно быть. Да, иногда некоторые авторы (с которыми, кстати, далеко не все согласны) предлагают эту точку опускать, но это не в нашем случае.

Четвертое. Еще есть рекомендация при вложенных кавычках внутренние оформлять елочками, внешние - лапочками. Я лично не сторонник этой идеи, нагляднее как раз наоборот, как у вас, но слышать приходилось неоднократно. Думаю, Вам о том знать не помешает.

Пятое. А зачем вам тут внешние кавычки? Они в оригинале есть - или это вы так цитату обозначили? Здесь этого лучше не делать, цитировать другим способом:

> Завтрак с Фредди! Гипнопедия — учитесь во сне! Курс читает Фредди! Покупайте акции „Райских кущ“!

или

> «Завтрак с Фредди! Гипнопедия — учитесь во сне! Курс читает Фредди! Покупайте акции „Райских кущ“!».

Вот тут нет сомнения, что к чему относится в части вашего и исходного текста.

(+)

Да, с учетом контекста - именно так. Восклицательный между кавычками, точка не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.
По первому: название фирмы без восклицательного.

По пятому: Это исходный текст в печатном издании. Голосовое рекламное объявление из колонок, скажем так.

Comment: Т.е. Внешние кавычки там в оригинале есть? Не понятно... Их клонок раздалось *«Завтрак с Фредди! Гипнопедия — учитесь во сне! Курс читает Фредди! Покупайте акции „Райских кущ“!»*? Такого плана? Тогда, может и правда, точка не нужна. Там очень путанное правило...

Comment: Да, именно, вот прямо так и написано, со всеми кавычками и зн. препинания (только вместо лапок - английские двойные кавычки; мне просто больше нр. лапки): «Завтрак с Фредди! Гипнопедия — учитесь во сне! Курс читает Фредди! Покупайте акции „Райских кущ!“».

Comment: Да лапки-то ладно. Это название фирмы, вопросов нет. А внешние, елочки, что тут значат? Если это прямая речь, то где слова автора, до или после? Если просто цитата, то точка, если не путаю, и правда не нужна. Если заголовок (можно и такое представит) - тоже.  Вопрос касается только точки после кавычек, но все равно интересно.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/5fbe63507b2968325d745f61587d78bb.png

Comment: Ах, вон оно что... Цитата без слов автора. Да, восклицательный знак должен стоять между кавычками, точка не нужна.